# vscode omnisharp cannot find class within new file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am using vscode to edit my project, and everytime I create a new file with a class in it, vscode doesn't pick up the changes even after I let unity compile and build a new sln.

In order for vscode to pick it up, I need to <kbd>F1</kbd> then search for `Restart Omnisharp`. vscode then picks up the changes.

This happens everytime I create a new unity file with a class within it. If I try referencing it from another class it says that it cannot find that class until I run the command `Restart Omnisharp`. Is there some way that I can fix this?

Comment: VSC is probably omitting it from the project because it was created outside VSC. VS does the same thing. Unit is supposed to rebuild the sln file (listing the new file as part of the project), but VSC doesn't seem to be refreshing. Try using the solution explorer to "list all files" and r-click -> include in project.

Comment: I installed a `Targeting pack` https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136 It seems to possibly have fixed the issue. I am still testing though...